# Is there a way to bind an onFocus Event to a TextField in NativeScript?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

Apparently I can't find a focus event handler in NativeScript's [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/text-field) or [API reference](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html) of TextFields elements. Am I wrong?

Or, is there a way to introduce the onFocus event extending the existing Nativescript's element?

(I am using typescript without Angular 2)

Comment: The focus event handler has been introduced in NativeScript on 25 Aug 2017
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/4730#event-1221079664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `on` method that is mentioned [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html#on). I don't know if this is what you are looking for but here is an example:

In XML:

```
<TextView id="textfield" textWrap="true" tap="textfieldTap"/>
```

In js file:

```
var myTextfield = page.getViewById("textfield");

myTextfield.on("tap", function() {
    console.log("Hello from the other side");
});
```

Also, there is another way to listen to focus event on TextField. As we have the `tap="textfieldTap"`inside the XML TextField tag, then we can declare a function in the js to listen to that event:

```
function textfieldTap(args) {
    console.log("Textfield tap " + args.text);
}
exports.textfieldTap = textfieldTap;
```

Comment: Ok, so there is not actually a `focus` event, but I can just use a Tap and do something while it gains the keyboard focus (it's not actually the same, but for my case it's enough).

Answer (score 1):

[A PR for adding `focus`](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/4730) is pending review. Won't be long before you can use it on `TextField` and `TextView` elements!